# SQL 2008 - Linked Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have to read a table in Linked Server with code, but I recived this message:
[image]

So,I think I've done all I can. Why my code doesn't work ?

This is part of my the code for the connection and query.

```
 public ObservableCollection<Model_Societa> CaricaComboSocieta(string sServer, string sDbSorgente, string StrConnectionString) //Popola combo SOCIETA
{

    StrConnectionString = "Data Source=HP-5CD6071;Initial Catalog=DB_TEST;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;";

    string Sql = "SELECT Soc_Cod, Sc_Rac FROM [HP-5CD6071].[DB_TEST].[dbo].[P00_So]";

    ObservableCollection<Model_Soc> res = new ObservableCollection<Model_Soc>();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(StrConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Sql, connection);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
            }
            ....
```

This is my linked servers

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='HP-5CD6071'
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'HP-55CD6071', 'false',   NULL, 'MyUSER', 'MyPassword'
```

[image]
[image]

My server linker is in "**sys.server**"
[image]

Comment: Did you try to run your query in SQL Mgmt Studio?  does it work?  If so, why not create a stored procedure and call it from your code instead?

Comment: HP-5CD6071 or HP-5CD6071CYP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main connection to the base server.  Your query is correct, but you're trying to connect to the linked server directly:

```
StrConnectionString = "Data Source=HP-5CD6071... <--This should be your main server
```

This will stay the same, using 4-part naming to connect to the linked server, from the server above:

```
SELECT Soc_Cod, Sc_Rac FROM [HP-5CD6071].[DB_TEST].[dbo].[P00_So]
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, can you show me the correct connection string  pls ?

Comment: @Alan392 Well it depends on what you want to do.  Right now, your connection string wants to connect directly to the linked server. ie. `HP-5CD6071` is the linked server, and also the server you're connecting to.  What this means is, you aren't using a linked server at all, you're just connecting directly to `HP-5CD6071`.  If you want to use the linked server, for permissions or whatever reason, then change the Data Source of your connection string to *the source server name*, aka the one you set the linked server up on above.

Comment: It looks like it's 'RO...' something.  You have it erased above.  Use that for the connection string.

Comment: I'm sorry but how can I connect to Linked server inmy stringconnection ?

Comment: @Alan392 You already have it in your query, `FROM [HP-5CD6071].[DB_TEST].[dbo].[P00_So]`.  That's all you need to do.

Comment: @Alan392 When you run a database query, you can generally just use `FROM table`, but you have the option to use up to 4 parts, as you have in your query: `[ServerNameOrLinkedServerName].[Database].[Schema].[Table]`.  That's all your need for the linked server, which you have.  Just change the connection string to your `RO...` server.